# I am trying to use prepared statements to insert values given in an array

Tags: express, mariadb

I am trying to INSERT values given in an array into my table, where each element of the array is a column in the table. Keep in mind this is for an API so the data is received through requests.
Here's the concerned parts in my code:
user.model.js:

```
User.create = function (newUser, result) {
console.log(Object.values(newUser));
dbConn.query("INSERT INTO user(user_fname, user_name, user_email, user_phone, user_is_admin) set ?", Object.values(newUser), function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        result(err, null);
    } else {
        console.log(res.insertId);
        result(null, res.insertId);
    }
});};
```

user.controller.js:

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
const new_user = new User(req.body);
console.log(req.body);

if (req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
    res.status(400).send({
        error: true,
        message: 'Please provide all required field'
    });
} else {
    console.log(new_user);
    User.create(new_user, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json({
            error: false,
            message: "User added successfully!",
            data: user
        });
    });
}};
```

In this last bit of code here is the output of the console.logs:

```
{
  user_fname: 'toto',
  user_name: 'titi',
  user_email: 'who@where.how',
  user_phone: '1010101010',
  user_is_admin: 'false'
}
User {
  fname: 'toto',
  name: 'titi',
  email: 'who@where.how',
  phone: '1010101010',
  is_admin: 'false'
}
[ 'toto', 'titi', 'who@where.how', '1010101010', 'false' ]
```

And last but not least here's the error message I get:

> error:  SqlError: (conn=357, no: 1064, SQLState: 42000) You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'set 'toto''
> at line 1 sql: INSERT INTO user(user_fname, user_name, user_email,
> user_phone, user_is_admin) set ? -
> parameters:['toto','titi','who@where.how','1010101010','false']

I'm clear on the fact my syntax is wrong but I can't seem to find anything that works. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer !
So as I thought my syntax was wrong, here's the correct way to do it:

```
User.create = function (newUser, result) {
    console.log(Object.values(newUser));
    dbConn.query("INSERT INTO user(user_fname, user_name, user_email, user_phone, user_is_admin) values(? , ? , ? , ? , ?)", Object.values(newUser), function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(err, null);
        } else {
            console.log(res.insertId);
            result(null, res.insertId);
        }
    });
};
```